# One-to-many relationship with two foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have two entities that form a many-to-many relationship. Each `Spectrum` is matched to another `Spectrum` with their similarity score stored in `SpectrumMatch`.

```
@Entity
public class Spectrum {
    private long id;
    private List<SpectrumMatch> matches;
    private List<SpectrumMatch> matches2;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = SpectrumMatch.class,
        mappedBy = "querySpectrum",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = Cascade.ALL)
    public List<SpectrumMatch> getMatches()

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = SpectrumMatch.class,
        mappedBy = "matchSpectrum",
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = Cascade.ALL)
    public List<SpectrumMatch> getMatches2()
}

@Entity
public class SpectrumMatch {
    private long id;
    @NotNull
    private Spectrum querySpectrum;
    @NotNull
    private Spectrum matchSpectrum;
    private double score;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "QuerySpectrumId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    public Spectrum getQuerySpectrum();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MatchSpectrumId", referencedColumnName = "Id")
    public Spectrum getMatchSpectrum()
}
```

In this code, the field `Spectrum.matches` contains all instances of `SpectrumMatch` where `SpectrumMatch.querySpectrum.id` is equal to that `Spectrum.id`.

However, I would like the field `Spectrum.matches` to contain all instances of `SpectrumMatch` where **either** `SpectrumMatch.querySpectrum.id` **or** `SpectrumMatch.matchSpectrum.id` equal to `Spectrum.id`.

Is it possible to implement such relationship?

Comment: Can you please elaborate this with example data. However, it seems like you are trying to compare id (which seems to be primary key) of two different Spectrum entities for equality, which is not possible.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that with JPA.  I would just map both query and match spectrums with two @OneToMany and have a getMatches() method that just appends the two lists together and returns it.

Comment: @JustinKSU Thank you, that's a good idea! My current implementation has two fields `Spectrum.matches` and `Spectrum.matches2`. The first is mapped with  @OneToMany to `querySpectrum`, and the second is mapped with @OneToMany to `matchSpectrum`. I'll add a getter that combines the two. However, I don't quite like having two extra methods that I don't use. I wonder if there is a cleaner solution.